# Upload image to S3 using presigned URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've been having a hell of a time getting a simple test to work. I am working on a mobile app in react native. I want to generate a presigned URL and use that url to upload a video file to s3. I'm currently just trying to test this approach by doing:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('./video.mp4')
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: 'video.mp4'}, (err, url) => {
  if (err) { console.log(err); }
  else {
    fetch(url, {
       method: 'PUT',
       body: file
    })
    .then(success => console.log(success.status))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  })
})
```

I get a 200 status code, but the 'file' that appears on S3 has 0 bytes. I noticed the same thing happens when I try to upload ANY file that I received via fs.readFileSync.
I managed to work around this temporarily be doing fs.readFileSync('./video.mp4', 'base64'), but this won't work in my app, because I need to access the video in it's original format, not as a base64 string. I also successfully used s3.upload, but that won't work in my app either, because I want to authenticate all my user's actions on my server before I give them permission to do an interaction with s3.
I'd really appreaciate some advice. I've been fiddling around with ContentTypes and ContentLengths all day.

Comment: You follow this way tu put and get object? -> [AWSJavaScriptSDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `FormData` to wrap your file with parameter named `file` like following:

```
var body = new FormData();
body.append('file', file);
fetch(url, { method: 'PUT', body: body });
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is awesome! Thank you. It would seem that the fetch API cannot handle node buffers. Both wrapping it in FormData as well as using the request API solve this issue.

Comment: Quick question: When I do this approach in react native itself, the video that ends up on S3 has some heads appended to the content at the beginning, making the file unplayable. Any ideas on how to upload the video without additional information being appended to it?

Comment: it is react-native issue, they use incorrect content-type for uploading.
I fixed the issue by using xhr for uploading. instead of using FormData+fetch, see xhr usage in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#xmlhttprequest and final key is `xhr.send({ uri: uri, type: 'video/mp4' })` for you.